# Display Litepicker inside specific div?

Tags: javascript, calendar, picker

I am using Litepicker: https://litepicker.com/
How can I make the div class="litepicker" appear inside another specific div of the page?

Comment: can you provide a sample of your code that you tried to execute this task? Whats the litepicker setup you are using regarding options, how you implimented the code thus far, that type of stuff? Did you ever figure this one out?